# How to include node-sass in nwjs (on windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, nw.js, node-sass, nwjs

I'm working on a multi-platform project in NW.js (node-webkit) and it has to use node-sass. The problem is that I can't seem to find any way to include it without an error on windows (x64).

Here's what I've tried:

1. Require as is
   Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
2. Build with node-sass' built in script and then require
   Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
3. Build with node-gyp
   Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
4. Build with nw-gyp (configure command fails)
   Error: name 'component' is not defined while evaluating condition 'OS=="win" and component=="shared_library" in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp

I've tested this on Windows 10 (x64), node v6.5.0, NW.js v0.16.1 and v0.17.0, node-sass (latest).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Faced similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is:

I created a wrapper around node-sass that calls node-sass as a child process (through the cli).

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
module.exports = function (options, cb) {
    // turn the options to node-sass cli args
    // something like this...
    exec(`node-sass ${agrs}`, execOptions, cb);
}
```

Works like a charm! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue (but on linux) and failed to find any answer why node-sass does not work and how to fix it. But [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js) works for me (worker+script). Of course it isn't so convenient as node-sass (i.e you need to handle imports in a special way), but for my needs it works fine.